# Java: How to reference and restart timer started by previous thread that has already ended?

Tags: java, timer

Basically, I have a program running as such:

A client puts some content onto a server through a socket connection. Once done, the connection is closed. The server will delete this data in about a minute if it doesnt hear from the client. Basically, the client is supposed to send a message to the server every minute to let the server know that it is still alive and as such, do not delete that particular data.

So when the client sends this message telling the server that it is still alive, the server will then proceed to restart that timer. The problem is I dont know how to find that instance of that timer to restart it. How can I go about doing this?

This is the flow I currently have:

Server running main thread

Server creates separate thread to receive client connection

Server receives data from client and saves it to a file.

Timer is started.

Socket is closed and thread is killed.

Before the minute ends, client creates new socket and sends a special message to server.

Again, server creates a new thread to handle the socket connection.

Now, how will this new thread find that timer instance from previous thread so it can restart it?

Thanks!

Comment: so us the relevant part of your code.

Comment: `Thread`'s die - not the `Thread`'s instance. Use the thread instance to get the timer.